# Función que dé False si todos los números son distintos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me dan el siguiente ejercicio:

> Escribir una función que tome una lista y devuelva `True` si hay dos números iguales, y `False` si son todos distintos.

Por ahora mi solución es esta:

```
def repetidos(lista):
  nueva=[]
  for elemento in lista:
    if elemento in nueva:
      return True
    
  for elemento in lista:
    if not elemento in nueva:
      return False
```

*Me da el error "AssertionError: False is not true"*.

¿Cómo podría resolver esto?

Comment: Nunca agregas nada a `nueva`. Por tanto, `elemento in nueva` es siempre `False`. La función siempre retorna `False` ¿Cual es tu algoritmo?

Comment: Hola Candid Moe, no esta dentro de ningún algoritmo. Son una serie de ejercicios que nos dan para prepararnos antes de empezar un curso.

Comment: No lo pongo como respuesta ya que el objetivo es que aprendas python, pero si tienes curiosidad por una forma rápida de hacer la comprobación de repetidos: `len(lista) != len(set(lista))`

Comment: Chema, esta respuesta es justo lo que buscaba. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución consiste en iterar a través de la lista, y en cada elemento, revisar si el elemento actual está repetido más adelante en la lista. Con el producto de cada comparación (`True` == repetido/`False` == no_repetido) se construye un iterable. Finalmente, la función `all` retorna `True` si *todos* los elementos del iterables son `True`, lo que significa que todos los elementos son únicos:

```
def unicos(lista):
    return all(lista[index] not in lista[index + 1:] for index in range(len(lista)-1))
```

**Demostración**

```
tests = [
    [],
    [1],
    [10, 20],
    [20, 20],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
]

for test in tests:
    print(unicos(test), test)
```

produce:

```
True []
True [1]
True [10, 20]
False [20, 20]
True [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
False [1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Gracias Candid!!!